# generate CSR & RSA Private key (for SSL Certificate)

Tags: ssl-certificate, rsa, private-key

I purchased SSL certificate for my domain, but I didn't receive PRIVATE key, and provider told me to generate RSA private key from my domain hosting... But in my dashboard, there is no option for this..
Is there available any php commands for this?

p.s. (`shell_exec` or similar not allowed on hosting)

Comment: Google for openssl and run this from the shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way! :

## =======STEP 1 ====

<<< **Generating Private Key (rsa/key/pem) & CSR [Certificate Signing Request]** >>>

Although there is a **[PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34962604/2377343)**,it can only generate PRIVATE KEY, not CSR.
You should better to use **openSSL** commands to get PRIVATE+ CSR keys


For **openssl** commands (typical [**examples**](http://www.thawte.nl/en/support/manuals/openssl/openssl+commands/)) use your Hosting SSH terminal (if it supports) or your Localhost (if you use **Apache/Wampserver/** or etc..):

-in CMD, type: `cd c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`, then execute such  command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr -config c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf
```

then it will ask you some questions... you should input **domain** name when it asks for "**common name**" (i.e.  **example.com**).... After you are done, in the same location `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\` you will see  Private key(**server.key**) and CSR key (**server.csr**). Go on...

## ========STEP 2 - Add CERTIFICATE (.crt) ========

Now, enter your **DOMAIN Register** dashboard (where you have SSL issued), and re-issue that. when it asks for CSR and PRIVATE KEY, enter the contents of the files we generated (open them in text editor)... Then you can go on (EMAIL verification is quickest way) and then you should get confirmation mail from your SSL provider (or Domain dashboard), where you can download the CERTIFICATE (xxxxxxxx.crt and xxxxxx.ca-bundle files)....  Then go to **HOSTING** dashboard,and in SSL section, use the codes CSR/PRIVATE/CRT keys appropriately !!!!!!

p.s. If you will get REDIRECT LOOP error, then you might have to re-install site/Wordpress.